# fatal: '1XX.1XX.XX.XX/mike/sampleprj.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: gitlab

I have a Linux Centos6.5 GitLab version 1.8.3.1(GitLab 6.8.1 3197990)server which has been setup with a public ip address without
 having an authorized domain name,sampleprj.git has been cloned from github.com properly and can be reach by browser 1XX.1XX.XX.XX,
tortoise git Git-1.9.4-preview20140929 has been installed at the windows 7 side, when I tried to pull the source code files to the 
Linux server, it shows errors:

```
git.exe pull --progress  "goman" master
```

Error

```
fatal: '1XX.1XX.XX.XX/mike/sampleprj.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (62 ms @ 09/10/2014 7:07:14 AM)
```

I checked /home/git/repositories/mike/sampleprj.git does exist,
remote manger 'goman' has URL:

```
1XX.1XX.XX.XX/mike/sampleprj.git
```

any help is appreciated

Mike

Comment: solved ,ok now:
windows git tortiose using default ssh protocol:
remote manage alias name: mike@1XX.1XX.XX.XX:/home/mike/mydir.git
with puttykey ppk file

git clone mike@1XX.1XX.XX.XX:/home/mike/sampleprj.git

go to the project folder
right mouse using git->push then you can push the source code files to the Linux server,
then you can pull down to your client side.

thanks 
Mike

Answer (score 0):

solved ,ok now:
windows git tortiose using default ssh protocol:
remote manage alias name: mike@1XX.1XX.XX.XX:/home/mike/mydir.git
with puttykey ppk file

git clone mike@1XX.1XX.XX.XX:/home/mike/sampleprj.git

go to the project folder
right mouse using git->push then you can push the source code files to the Linux server,
then you can pull down to your client side.

thanks 
Mike